# Бот не реагирует на условие

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot
import random
```

Есть функция которая возвращает рандомно тексты из массива

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot("....")
def random_text():
  array = ['Some text-1','Some text-2']
  return random.choice(array)
```

Когда боту напишут "Рандомный текст" то будет вызвана функция

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def button_reactions(message):
  if message.chat.type == 'private':
     if message.text == 'Радномный текст ':
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, random_text())
```

Теперь когда функция вернет "Some text-1" или "Some text-2",то я хочу создать условие:

```
 if bot.send_message == 'Some text-1':
    pHoto = open('Путь к фотографии или', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,pHoto,caption=None)
```

То есть при условии, если бот выведет "Some text-1" он также должен прислать фото, но условие не реагирует

Comment: bot.senf_message - это функция. А вы её сравнивает со строкой, и ожидаете, что они будут равны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объединил два куска кода, попробуйте:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def button_reactions(message):
  if message.chat.type == 'private':
     if message.text == 'Радномный текст ':
         text = random_text()
         bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text)

         if text == 'Some text-1':
             pHoto = open('Путь к фотографии или', 'rb')
             bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, pHoto, caption=None)
```

Comment: Да работает, спасибо)